# How to update a table in shiny every hour OR when the user presses a refresh button?

Tags: r, api, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I have managed to get this, admittedly, very basic table to update on its own using the invalidateLater() function and also to update when pressing the refresh button however, I haven't managed to combine them both whereby the table would update every given time period OR when then user presses the button. Please could you give me a hand, I have added my code below!

```
if (interactive()) {
  # table example
  shinyApp(
    ui = fluidPage(
      fluidRow(
        column(12,
               tableOutput('table'),
               actionButton("refresh", "Update")
        )
      )
    ),
    server = function(input, output) {
      observeEvent(input$refresh, {
        invalidateLater(15000)
        spot_gold <- fromJSON("https://api.metals.live/v1/spot")[[1]][[1]]
        spot_silver <- fromJSON("https://api.metals.live/v1/spot")[[2]][[1]]
        spot_platinum <- fromJSON("https://api.metals.live/v1/spot")[[3]][[1]]
        spot_palladium <- fromJSON("https://api.metals.live/v1/spot")[[4]][[1]]
        spot_prices <- cbind(spot_gold, spot_silver, spot_platinum, spot_palladium)
        output$table <- renderTable(spot_prices)
      })
    }
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `invalidateLater()` you placed inside your `observeEvent()` gets `isolated()`. One way to trigger on `input$refresh` OR `invalidateLater()` is by using `observe()` instead of `observeEvent()`

```
observe({
  input$refresh
  invalidateLater(15000)

  spot_gold <- ...
  ...
})
```